# MPI update elements of an array based on maximum in nested loops

Tags: c, parallel-processing, nested, mpi

I am currently trying to make the following code parallel in MPI. Amax is a zero vector at the beginning and for each iteration it needs to be updated. I was checking MPI_reduce() function to get the local maximums and then obtain the global maximum but I could not figure out how this can be done to update elements of an array instead of finding a maximum value over a volume.

I wonder what is the best way to do this.

Thanks!

```
for (k = zstart; k < zend; k++)
    {     
     for (j = ystart; j < yend; j++)  
         { 
          for (i = xstart;i < xend; i++)
              {             
               for(t=tstart;t<tend;t++) 
                  {
                    Smax[t]= i*j*k

                    if(Smax[t]>Amax[t])
                       { 
                         Amax[t]=Smax[t];
                       }
                   }                         
              }  
         }      
    }
```

Comment: `i`, `j` and `k` are the same on every iteration of `t in [tstart, tend)`. You should probably assign `i*j*k` to a single `smax` variable in the outer `i` loop and leave just the comparison `smax > Amax[t]` in the innermost loop.